# Half ellipsis extrusion

Tags: modifiers, extrude

[image]

Hi, i'm new with blender, i was already making some things and reading many questions & answers here to learn. But now i would like to star with some personal projects, and here is where the problems begin...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to bend a flat font/mesh with a Curve modifier. After the modifier has been applied, the outer edges can be extruded down and scaled to a zero depth - in my case that is the Z direction.

[image: Curved Font]

Comment: Great! I Will try, but this is advanced level!!! Thanks